# Issue with the Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm new to the world of Java programming trying to input values through the scanner class using the code below.

The issue is the Scanner is not opening up the console for user input and its displaying the average value to be zero by default. Debugging the console is throwing a file not found exceptions error. Please advise...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Avg {

  int no = 0;
  int sum = 0;

  void average(){
    System.out.println("pls enter 5 numbers");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i = 0; i > 5;  ) {
      no = s.nextInt();
      sum = no + sum;
      i++;
    }
    int avg = sum / 5;
    System.out.println(avg);
  }

  public static void main(String[] h){
    Avg s = new Avg();
    s.average();
  }
}
```

Comment: `sum/5` is always 0. Write `sum/5.0`.

Comment: for loop condition is wrong.

Comment: twist the '>' to '<' ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first for loop should have `i < 5` condition but it is `i > 5` in your code. So it makes 0 iterations.

Answer (score 1):

`For` loop is having issue. You set the value of `i` to `0` and check if it is greater than `5`. Not at all possible. it turns `false`. Please change the conditional check to

```
for(int i=0;i<5;){
no=s.nextInt();
sum=no+sum;
i++;
}
```

Otherwise, `i` will be always lesser than `5` and will not get inside the loop. So, the value of `avg` will be always `0`